# JQuery to display on form last time Datatable reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Here's my table. I was wondering whether there is a JQuery snippet or does it have to be done long hand with JavaScript? Either way help very much appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fixtureTable = $('#fixtures').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/fixtures",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        //deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            { data: 'marketName' },
            { data: 'selectionName' },
            { data: 'bookmakerName' },
            { data: 'couponName' },
            {
            data: null,
            render: function (data, type, row) {
                return Math.round((row.backOdds / row.exchangeType.layOdds) * 100 - 100) + '%';
            }
    }
        ],

    });
    setInterval(function () {
        fixtureTable.ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: _JQuery snippet for what?_ You have not explained your problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorted thanks.

```js
            setInterval(function () {
                fixtureTable.ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload
            
                var currentDate = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
                    hour: "numeric",
                    minute: "numeric"
                });
                $("#LastUpdateTime").val(currentDate);
            }, 10000);
```

```html
    @Html.TextBox("LastUpdateTime", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```